# Can i defrag windows partitions without affecting linux partitions?

Tags: defragment

Should I use any defragment software or just use builtin windows defrag manager ? I have three OSs installed in my pc. I have Fedora 17 x64,Ubuntu 12.04 x86 and Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

How can I defragment Ubuntu and fedora partitions ? Does running a defragment software causes damage to the Hard Disk ?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your Ubuntu and Fedora partitions will use the ext4 file system, that has a higher degree of resiliency against disk fragmentation than the Windows-used NTFS. This translates to this recommendation:

- Use whatever you think is OK (I use the built-in utility) for Windows (NTFS) defragmentation. It will not touch your Ubuntu/Fedora partitions.
- Do nothing on the Ubuntu/Fedora side of things, unless you run into a problem, that can be tracked down to disk fragmentation. In this case ask on a dedicated Linux FS list.